# A (classical) voice equivalent to the Henle Difficulty System

Tags: voice, grading

(This is my first post here so please be lenient :) )

Background: I am a pianist and recently, I have become a [classical] singer.

Recall the Henle 'Levels of Difficulty' rankings for piano pieces, found [here](http://www.henleusa.com/en/the-publishing-house/levels-of-difficulty-piano.html). I am looking for something similar for (classical) songs.

(Please try to keep discussion away from 'music cannot be ranked,' for yes, I know this fully well. I am just looking for a relatively general guide to repertoire difficulty.)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the pieces set for the various grades of ABRSM exams?  They might give you some pointers

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! Providing lists and song titles is outside the remit of this site, however, check various exam boards syllabi. World wide. JimM has suggested a U.K. based board - there's also Trinity and LCM here, and undoubtedly each state in U.S. has there own take on this. I know there are several in Oz also. Google is your saviour!